# struct tm --> acceso desde función como puntero

Tags: c, gcc

Tengo la llamada a una función de la manera siguiente:

```
void DS3232_Hora( uint8_t direccion, uint8_t *hora, struct tm *elTiempo, uint8_t enBruto)
```

El tema es que no se cómo llenar la estructura elTiempo con datos.

Haciendo así:

```
elTiempo.tm_sec= hora[ 2];
```

Me da el error:
librerias/DS3232.h:153:12: error: petición del miembro ‘tm_sec’ en algo que no es una estructura o unión
elTiempo.tm_sec= hora[ 2];
Agrdezco vuestra ayuda, gracias!!!

************EDITADO por respuestas *******************

Hola,

La función es esta ( dentro de DS3232.h):

```
void DS3232_Hora( uint8_t direccion, uint8_t *hora, struct tm elTiempo, uint8_t enBruto)
{
    uint8_t horas;

    if( enBruto==1) // Entrega los datos según salen del RTC-DS3232
    {
        DS3232_DameDatos( hora, 0, 3, direccion);
    }
    else // Entregamos la hora dentro de la estructura tiempo que se debe declarar al iniciar el módulo.
    {
            DS3232_DameDatos( hora, 0x00, 3, direccion);
            convertidorSegMin( hora);
            convertidorHoras( hora);
            
            elTiempo.tm_sec= hora[ 2];
            elTiempo.tm_min= hora[ 1];
            elTiempo.tm_hour= hora[ 0];
            
    }
}
```

Y la llamo desde el main.c principal. Aquí la declaro así:

```
/**/#define F_CPU 16000000UL
#define UART_BAUD  57600
#define F_I2C 400000UL
#define SCL_Frequency (( F_CPU/ F_I2C)- 16)/ 2
#define MENSAJES 1

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "librerias/manejo_uart.h"
#include "librerias/Arduino_Nano_Cabeceras.h"
#include "librerias/mensajes.h"
//#include "librerias/AtMega328p-TWI.h"
#include "librerias/DS3232.h"
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <time.h>

struct tm elTiempo;

uint8_t I2C_init( void)
{
    TWBR= SCL_Frequency;
}


int main(void) {

    // Inicialización de la consola
    uart_init();
    FILE uart_output = FDEV_SETUP_STREAM(uart_putchar, NULL, _FDEV_SETUP_WRITE);
    FILE uart_input = FDEV_SETUP_STREAM(NULL, uart_getchar, _FDEV_SETUP_READ);
    FILE uart_io = FDEV_SETUP_STREAM(uart_putchar, uart_getchar, _FDEV_SETUP_RW);

    stdout = &uart_output;
    stdin  = &uart_input;
    // Fin inicialización de la consola.
    if ( MENSAJES) { printf( "log-> %s A %u bauds.\n", consola_init, UART_BAUD);}
    uint8_t tmp;

    uint8_t direccion= 104;

    uint8_t init_hora= 0;
    uint8_t init_fecha= 3;


    uint8_t hora[ 3];
    uint8_t fecha[ 4];
    uint8_t temperatura[ 5];
    uint8_t registrosControl[ 2];
    uint8_t SRAM[ 0xFF- 0x14];

    AtMega328p__TWI_init();
while( 1)
{

    DS3232_Hora( direccion, hora, elTiempo, 0);
    printf("%d:%d:%d\n", hora[ 0], hora[ 1], hora[ 2]);
    _delay_ms( 100);

    DS3232_Fecha( direccion, fecha, &elTiempo, 0);
    printf("%d/%d/%d\n", fecha[ 1], fecha[ 2], fecha[ 3]);
    _delay_ms( 100);
    
    elTiempo.tm_sec= hora[ 2];

    if( MENSAJES) { printf( "Segundos: %d\n", elTiempo.tm_sec);}
    _delay_ms( 1000);
/*
    DS3232_Temperatura( direccion, temperatura);
    printf("%d.%dºC\n", temperatura[ 3], temperatura[ 4]);
    _delay_ms( 1000);
*/

/*
    DS3232_SRAM( direccion, SRAM);

    printf("Valor de SRAM antes de escribir:0x00-> %d\n", SRAM[ 0]);

    if( MENSAJES) { printf( "Salida de la función: %d\n",DS3232_Write_unDato( direccion, 0x06, 0x14));}

    DS3232_SRAM( direccion, SRAM);
    uint8_t i;
    for( i=0;i<10; i++)
    {
    printf("Valor de SRAM[ %d]-> %d\n", i, SRAM[ i]);
*/
/*
I2C_Write( direccion, 0x0E);
if( MENSAJES) { printf( "Valor antes: %d\n",I2C_Read( direccion));}
if( MENSAJES) { printf( "Salida de escritura: %d\n",DS3232_Write_unDato( direccion, 0b0000000, 0x0E));}
I2C_Write( direccion, 0x0E);
if( MENSAJES) { printf( "Valor después: %d\n",I2C_Read( direccion));}
*/
/*
    //Acceso a la memory 24C32 
    if( MENSAJES) { printf( "Salida de la función: %d\n",I2C_Write( 0x57, 0x10));}
 */
  
                        /* De aquí para abajo el programa. */
    }
}
```

El error que me reporta es el indicado al principio.

Indicar que este código es compilado para microcontroladores, en concreto para un atmega328p y compliado con gcc-avr.

Si lo pruebo en gcc con el siguiente código, va bien.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

void tiempo( struct tm *hora)
{
    hora->tm_sec= 12;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct tm elTiempo;
    
    elTiempo.tm_sec= 10;
    printf("VAlor antes de llamar a la función, %d\n", elTiempo.tm_sec);
    tiempo( &elTiempo);
    printf("VAlor después de llamar a la función, %d\n", elTiempo.tm_sec);
}
```

Sds.

Comment: Buen día, `*elTiempo` es un apuntador, intenta con `->` es decir `elTiempo->tm_sec= hora[ 2];` [lectura recomendada](https://codingornot.com/05-apuntadores-trabajando-con-estructuras)

Comment: Hola,

GRacias por responder.

No funciona, pero gracias de todos modos.

Sds.

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar el resto del código? Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). De esa forma podrá ser más fácil ayudarte a encontrar el problema. Saludos

Comment: Hola,

Edito el mensaje original ya que como respuesta no me deja ya que es muy largo

Comment: Gracias, de hecho siempre que agregues algo de información a tu pregunta debe ir como edición de la publicación original, nunca como comentario. Por lo que veo, la estructura elTiempo no está definida ¿La tienes en algún otro lugar?

Comment: Hola,

la estructura elTiempo está definida en el main.c principal.

Answer (score 0):

Después de analizar los comentarios y revisar el código, parece que [el comentario de HeytalePazguato estaba en lo correcto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/529725/struct-tm-acceso-desde-funci%c3%b3n-como-puntero/529740#comment938205_529725), pero la función se debe llamar apuntando a la dirección donde se encuentra la estructura.

Al final quedó de la manera:

```
DS3232_Hora( direccion, hora, &elTiempo, 0);
```